# Contains function in windows search query doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to execute the following query on a mapped drive

```
"SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemUrl, System.Search.AutoSummary, System.Search.Contents FROM JulioCompartido.SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file://JulioCompartido/Comp' and CONTAINS('"a*"')"
```

this command return "Got OleDbException, error code is 0x80004005L(Unspecified error)"

The query works correctly if I do not add the contains clause

```
"SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemUrl, System.Search.AutoSummary, System.Search.Contents FROM JulioCompartido.SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file://JulioCompartido/Comp'"
```

I have stolen different ways to call the function contains

- CONTAINS('"a*"')
- CONTAINS('\"a*\"')
- CONTAINS('a*')
- CONTAINS('a')

Also adding the name of the column as the first parameter, 
with and without quotes

- CONTAINS(System.Search.Contents, '\"a*\"')
- CONTAINS("System.Search.Contents", '\"a*\"')

I have tried combined all the previous options

Comment: Have you tried "like" instead of contains, so like '%a%'

Comment: This return "Got OleDbException, error code is 0x80040E14L"

Comment: depends on what actually you wrote.. cant tell without the full text

Comment: "SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemUrl, System.Search.AutoSummary, System.Search.Contents FROM JulioCompartido.SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file://JulioCompartido/Comp' WHERE System.Search.Contents LIKE '%a%'"

Comment: "SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemUrl, System.Search.AutoSummary, System.Search.Contents FROM JulioCompartido.SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file://JulioCompartido/Comp' AND System.Search.Contents LIKE '%a%'"
This works correcly!

Comment: well there you go then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contains is not a valid call under WMI, you need to use "like".. such as field like "%a%"

As you discovered you also cant have two where clauses.  You wanted to and them together.. so you ended up with

`WHERE scope ='file://JulioCompartido/Comp' AND System.Search.Contents LIKE '%a%'"` which worked.